# What exactly do the module ProtocolSupportModule?

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5, iis-10

In the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview) they say that `ProtocolSupportModule` Implements the supports which allow or turn off keep-alive support via configuration. I don't understand what it's mean exactly ?

I saw that for example without `ProtocolSupportModule` the `custom headers` will not work. So it's not only about `TRACE` and `OPTIONS`

I Think now that maybe `ProtocolSupportModule` is connected to this in the `web.config`

```
<httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true">
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
  </customHeaders>
  <redirectHeaders>
    <clear />
  </redirectHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This seam to correspond to what the doc say (keepalive, redirect and custom header)

Comment: IIS is not open sourced, so you won't be able to know **everything**. Also it does not matter that much.